# How to download mongodb using anaconda in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda

there are only mongodb  packages for linux and mac Does anyone know where to find mongodb package for windows . If so then can u post me the link

Answer (score 1):

1. Download mongodb from its official website: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
2. Create a mongodb config file inside the folder where MongoDB was installed and type the following:

   ### store data here

   dbpath=D:\mongodb\data

   ### all output go here

   logpath=D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

   ### log read and write operations

   diaglog=3
3. Open CMD and navigate to the place where mongod got installed, navigate to the `bin` folder. Type `mongod --config D:\mongodb\mongo.config` to start mongodb server.
4. Then type `mongo` to enter mongodb interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

As I know anaconda is a package for the IDE/Text editor, that help you for code faster is not a package manager for dev, they package are for perform it's own platform.

If you want to use mongo DB in windows you need download mongodb

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav

then just install pymongo using pip

```
pip install pymongo
```

and that's all just run mongo from command line.